# What type of language construct is Rails' "validates"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just starting to grok Ruby. My background is in .NET and PHP. In Rails, and I'm sure in other frameworks as well, I see stuff like this on classes:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true
end
```

What exactly is "validates"? Is it a function? If it's a function, how does the validation actually work since you don't tell the validates function which model you are validating?

Where can I read more about how this actually works behind the scenes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's... a little complicated - but the short answer is that `validates` is a class method of `Person`, inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`. That line could equally have been written `validates(:terms_of_service, :acceptance => true)`.

Ruby, like a lot of interpreted languages, effectively "executes" class definitions, so when it encounters the `validates` line, it sees it as a method call where the current `self` object is the instance of the `Class` class representing the class `Person`, inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`. It calls the method, which has the effect of hooking a validator into the `Person` class.

You can read about the method [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates) - but do note that that adds *more* confusion, since it lists the method as an *instance* method of `ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods`. Huh? Well, Ruby has two ways of taking functionality from another `Module` and putting it into your class - you can either `include` the module (in which case its instance methods become instance methods of your class), or `extend` the module (in which case its instance methods become *class* methods of your class).

So, to summarise: `validates` is declared as an instance method of `ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods`, which is `extend`ed into `ActiveRecord::Base`. Therefore, `validates` is a class method of `ActiveRecord::Base` and, by inheritance, `Person`. The line in your code snippet is just a method call.

However, having said all that, most Rubyists and Railsists will largely ignore those facts; `validates` is what's called a "decorator", and most people will simply read it as a statement *about* `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a special callback method that gets called to validate data before it's saved to the database.

A callback, more generally, is a method that "hooks into" an object or code module/library in such a way that the method gets called automatically when certain events occur. In this case, the event that calls the set of validation methods is the act of trying to save something to the database. This is useful because, before you write new or updated information to your database, you want to make sure it's valid, in order to prevent bad data from leaking into your application.

The following methods trigger validations, and will save the object to the database only if all validations pass (in the literal sense, this means all the validation methods must return a value that is not `false`, or `nil`, etc., otherwise validation is considered to have failed):

- create
- create!
- save
- save!
- update
- update_attributes
- update_attributes!

"Methods" in Ruby are very similar to the concept of functions in other languages. In many cases you can think of them interchangeably - they declare some functionality, they take parameters as input, and they return a result as output.

More detail on validations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Ruby (and Rails) use "callbacks" in many different situations - pretty much anytime you want some method to be called as a result of some event occuring.

More reading on callbacks: http://www.khelll.com/blog/ruby/ruby-callbacks/

Comment: Thanks for the response. So does the method actually belong to the class? If so, I assume it can use late static binding to know which model it is validating? I'm just not used to seeing method calls sitting in a class like that. Usually they are within other methods or something.

Comment: It's a class method. Ruby has an implicit receiver of self when a method is called without one, which would be your ActiveRecord subclass in this case. Rails maintains a list of validations behind the scenes, and when the validate method executes on class load, it adds a callback to the chain. The callbacks are examined after the methods listed in @normalocity's answer.

Comment: The set of validation methods come from the ActiveRecord::Validations ( http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html ) - that link provides several "show source" links that will reveal the actual source code of how the validation methods are declared, and may shed some more light on it for you.